# Check element type in BeautifulSoup 3

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

How can I check if a `Tag` element is of a certain type, for example a `div`, in BS3?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You are looking for the [tag *name*](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#name):

```
if element.name == 'div':
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('<div><span></span></div>')
>>> print soup.find('div').name
div
```

This attribute hasn't changed between BeautifulSoup 3 and 4. I strongly recommend you use BeautifulSoup 4; all development on BS3 has stopped, the last release for that version was over 2 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

and probably the next thing you want to test about the element after its tag name,  is its attributes, so here is an example:

```
if element.name == 'div' and element.attrs['class'][0] == 'album':
```