# test if a tag is table in beautifulsoup

Tags: html, beautifulsoup

I use beautifulsoup to parse a web page with complex structure. So I need to do parsing works accourding thta tag type.

```
for child in fields = soup.find("fields",{"id":"A3a7d"}).children:
    // if child is table do something
    // elseif child is span do something
    // else
```

I've tryed to use `type(child)`, which only get `bs4.element.Tag`, how to check if the child is a table tag?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: These will give you examples on `IF` statements in **Beautiful Soup**: [How to Scrape a Website with Beautiful Soup](https://www.linode.com/docs/applications/big-data/how-to-scrape-a-website-with-beautiful-soup/) and [Scraping Reddit with Python and BeautifulSoup 4](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/scraping-reddit-python-scrapy)

Comment: Just as the question titile, how to check if the tag is a table tag?

Comment: Your link is nothing to do with telling if a tag is table.

Comment: If you have a look in the links, they will actually hold some of the information you need. But if you need me to be explicit.. have you tried `if element.name == 'table':` like this example...... [Check element type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22565595/11700321)

Comment: @EGC Thank you,I'm new to beautifulsoup. It save a lot of work, thans again.

Comment: No problem. I'm voting this as duplicate to close this issue!